# Urllib.request ou Request?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Estou estudando web scraping e em muitos guias eu vi exemplos em que são usados `urllib.request` e `request.get`. Pelo que testei e entendi os dois fazem as mesma coisa.

Então, qual a diferença entre eles e quando usar cada um?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que não seja `request.get`, mas sim no plural `requests.get`, se este for o caso, entenda que `requests` (https://pypi.org/project/requests/) não é uma lib "nativa", ela geralmente é instalada a parte e possui uma série de outras libs (ou seja esta quase para um framework para trabalhar com HTTP) e métodos que facilitam trabalhar com (isto tudo afirmação dos desenvolvedores):

- Keep-Alive e Connection Pooling
- Dominios internacionais e URLs
- Sessions com persistência de Cookie
- Browser-style SSL Verification
- Content Decoding automático
- Basic/Digest Authentication
- Um "elegante" meio trabalhar com cookies Key/Value Cookies
- Decompression automatica
- Unicode Response Bodies
- Suporte para HTTP(S) Proxy
- Multipart File Uploads
- Streaming Downloads
- Connection Timeouts
- Requisições em "partes" (Chunked)
- suporte para `.netrc`

Já `urlib2` e `urllib`, são geralmente nativos e vieram mudando conforme as versões do python. O intuito mesmo dos desenvolvedores ao criar o `requests` foi para facilitar neste "porte" entre versões do python ou entre problemas complexos sobre o HTTP do qual o urllib não faz e você teria que resolver na mão e ele foi criado pensando no [**PEP 20**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Em minha opinião se vai fazer algo simples, que não precisa de muito vá de `urllib` mesmo (sendo a versão 3.7+ do Python), se for distribuir para mais de uma versão do Python ai complica, mas poderia apenas checar se `urllib` está disponível com um `try` junto ao `import` e então tentar usar `urllib2` (creio que em Python2 apenas, me corrijam se confundi algo aqui).

Mas se vai fazer uma série de trabalhos complexos, precisa acelerar o desenvolvimento e quer algo que facilite (ainda mais se vai fazer algo como um Web scraping), então instale o `requests` com pip:

```
pip install requests
```

E comece pela documentação: https://requests.kennethreitz.org/pt_BR/latest/index.html